Car chase movie where hero tries to get to pregnant wife
The movie is about this guy (wrongly accused of something) trying to run away from the cops to meet his girlfriend/wife, who, if I remember correctly is pregnant. Here are the bits I remember from the movie:

The lead character somehow evades the cops throughout the movie;
I also remember him buying a scanner from a store to learn about the cops' next move;
The other scene I remember is that he calls in to a popular radio show to send his messages to his girlfriend/wife;
In the end the cops catch him near the border of Mexico.

I remember watching it in the late 90's.

Reminds me of The Chase, apart from the pregnant girlfriend/wife.

Pregnant wife, car chases and being arrested at the Mexican border can be found in Due Date, but don't remember the rest being there.

@Walt Its a much older movie, I remember watching in the late 90's

@AndrewMartin Not sure if it was a comedy movie, but I have to watch the The Chase

This could be the 1997 remake of Vanishing Point with Viggo Mortensen and Jason Priestley:

When his wife goes into a troubled labor while he is on the road over 1200 miles away James Kowalski, an ex race car driver and a former Army Ranger, attempts to elude police while trying to get home. After numerous chases he turns into a Native American reservation and reflects on his life, and his wife. He then heads off to break through an impenetrable police and FBI roadblock. 

James gets a scanner at some point and is helped throughout the movie by a radio DJ called "The Voice" (played by Priestly). Here's the trailer:



